# Is there a substitute for an "average" which best inherently represents data, rather than reducing it to one or another aspect?

Tags: function, functional-data-analysis

I was thinking about the arithmetic average as a type of metric or a representation of data. Maybe there is a mathematical argument for the non-arbitrariness of that function. I think something like hashing creates the illusion of total information loss on the inputs, yet technically, the information is actually still preserved. Whereas the arithmetic average does cause a loss in information, but not so much that the result is completely arbitrary - it does indicate something, about the inputs.

The thing is, I am pretty sure in math there are examples of various metrics, norms, representations, etc, which transform an object in a certain way which is more compelling, let's say. Like, maybe that representation has even stronger indicative information about the object that got transformed.

However, the average is not just to alter the form of the object without changing its inherent information - like encryption. It does cause some information loss, but it produces (to an extent) a result that we take as useful; it has some interesting, interpretable meaning.

The issue is the aspects of information that are lost, via an average. An average is not a perfect representation of an object because of aspects of the object it leaves out; it fails to represent it completely, so there's a missing part of the story.

From that perspective, the most accurate representation of an object is itself: it is the most complete, non-reduced specification of everything that defines it.

I am sure there are various kinds of analysis you can do on some data, a logistic curve or logistic regression or something, calculate the variance or distribution, etc.

I am wondering if there is some most canonical representation of data which, unlike an average, captures fundamental information without excluding part of it.

It's sort of an open-ended mathematical question but maybe if we consider we have n points in m dimensional space, is there an ordering on functions we can apply, so our choice of representation is not arbitrarily selecting one possible function amongst many others?

It's sort of a question about capturing "all" the information, even if via multiple distinct functions.

Comment: You may be interested in the concept of sufficiency https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic

Comment: @JohnMadden sufficiency is useful within a parametric context. It seems to me that the OP is interested in nonparametric summaries.

Comment: This question can be made rigorous or it can answered informally. The key is whether you can go backwards,  and reconstruct what is of interest from a summary; and sometimes you can and sometimes you can't. For example a binary variable with values 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 can be summarized as 10 values with mean 0.7 and that is all you may care about. But you lose track of the difference between that and 1 0 1 0 1 0 1  1 1 1 and many other orderings of the same values by focus on mean 0.7 and sample size 10. So, the key is what do you regard as information and what do you feel free to ignore?